# How to display firstly vowels and then consonants in string?

Tags: javascript, string

Basically I want to display vowels and consonants from string but I quite don't understand why my code below doesn't work properly.

```
const word = "javascriptloops";
let array = word.split("");
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (
    array[i] === "a" ||
    array[i] === "e" ||
    array[i] === "i" ||
    array[i] === "o" ||
    array[i] === "u"
  ) {
    console.log(array[i]);
    array.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
for (let item of array) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

The result it shows is: [The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnJjj.png)

Can someone explain what's the reason why it doesn't include this second "o" with the vowels?

Comment: You are modifying the array as you're iterating over it, which means your indices will become increasingly incorrect. Try e.g. `console.log(array[i], i, array.length, array.join(","));`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're modifying the same array you're iterating over, you'll need to "skip back" one cell after removing an item.

That is, add `i--;` after `array.splice(i, 1);`

To visualize this, you can try

```
console.log(array.join(""), array.length);
console.log(" ".repeat(i) + "^", i);
```

in your loop.

Without this skipping back, the output is

```
javascriptloops 15
 ^ 1
jvascriptloops 14
  ^ 2
jvscriptloops 13
     ^ 5
jvscrptloops 12
        ^ 8
```

With the fix, it's

```
javascriptloops 15
 ^ 1
jvascriptloops 14
  ^ 2
jvscriptloops 13
     ^ 5
jvscrptloops 12
        ^ 8
jvscrptlops 11
        ^ 8
```

This is made even more obvious with a string with more subsequent vowels, say, `daemonium`:

No fix:

```
daemonium 9
 ^ 1
demonium 8
   ^ 3
demnium 7
    ^ 4
```

With fix:

```
daemonium 9
 ^ 1
demonium 8
 ^ 1
dmonium 7
  ^ 2
dmnium 6
   ^ 3
dmnum 5
   ^ 3
```

Answer (score 0):

AKX explained it beautifully. So this is just an alternative if you want `vowels` and `consonants` individually.

```js
const word = "javascriptloops";
let vowel = word.match(/[aeiou]/g);
let consonants = word.match(/[^aeiou]/g);

console.log(vowel);
console.log(consonants);
```

If you want result in one loop then you could do something like

```js
const word = "javascriptloops",
  vowel = [],
  consonants = [];

for (let char of word) {
  if (char.match(/[aeiou]/)) vowel.push(char);
  else consonants.push(char);
}

console.log(vowel);
console.log(consonants);
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I'd do in a real life situation too :)

Comment: It's more sensible with regular expression . Thanks for your help.